# How can I set a custom path helper for a Resource in go Buffalo?

Tags: go, buffalo

With a GET route, I can do

```
        app.GET("/", HomeHandler).Name("CustomName")
```

But with a Resource, the `.Name()` function is no longer available

Comment: unfortunetely I could not find any support for that. Here on [buffalo/route_mappings](https://github.com/gobuffalo/buffalo/blob/v1.0.1/route_mappings.go#L172) we can see that the resource name is automatically the name of the type informed

Comment: I don’t think this is possible. The resource is intended to provide all those defaults quickly and as a result you lose the ability to customize. You can convert from a resource to normal routes and have that flexibility.